# How to check whether an array contains a value of something?

Tags: arrays, string, element

I have an array. And i'd like to check if that index or that element of array contains the value of a string or a number:

```
var arrayArray = ['cool bmw', 'wew toyota', 'try honda'];
```

I'd like to check if some value inside of the element is existing.

Example on index 2 i'd like to check whether it contains the word toyota.

Comment: Hi Anon, which programming language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Anon Is your question about JavaScript? Your comments on Arvind's answer seem to imply this. Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

> Example on index 2 i'd like to check whether it contains the word toyota.

You need `String.indexOf()`:

```js
var arrayArray = ['cool bmw', 'wew toyota', 'try honda'];
var checkWord = 'toyota';
var position = arrayArray[1].indexOf(checkWord);
var found = (-1 !== position);
console.log('found = ',found);
```

Here, `indexOf()` will return `-1` if no match found else will return index position of first occurrence starting from `0`.

> What if i didn't indicate the [1] i'd like to check it in a for loop how do i check on that?

```js
var arrayArray = ['cool bmw', 'wew toyota', 'try honda'];
var checkWord = 'toyota';
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; arrayArray.length > i; i++) {
  if (-1 !== arrayArray[i].indexOf(checkWord)) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
console.log('found =', found);
```

Comment: i'm quite confused on that 'var found = -1' can you please explain it. and is there any other way to check beside this code?

Comment: What if i didn't indicate the [1] i'd like to check it in a for loop how do i check on that?

Comment: much oblige of you being so responsive